# Unable to animate expand collapse due to !important in CSS

Tags: jquery, css, slidetoggle

I am trying to implement a simple expand/collapse in a menu using jquery's slideToggle. I am working in a monster-corporate website which has some CSS files that we can't touch (called in server), CSS files which have several !important declarations, notably visibility: visible !important; and display: block !important; . 
These declarations interfere with slideToggle's mechanism, and although there is an animation, the moment it ends the menu hops back to being "expanded". It's pretty clear here in the **jsfiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/h2PVT/ . Here's also the code inline:

```
<div class="AspNet-Menu-Vertical" id="zz1_CurrentNav">
        <ul class="AspNet-Menu">
            <li class="AspNet-Menu-Leaf">
                <a href="/dg/ias/whoweare/Pages/whoweare.aspx" class="AspNet-Menu-Link">
                    Who we are</a>
            </li>
            <li class="AspNet-Menu-WithChildren  AspNet-Menu-Selected">
                <a href="/dg/ias/whatwedo/Pages/Whatwedo.aspx" class="AspNet-Menu-Link  AspNet-Menu-Selected">
                    What we do</a>
                <ul>
                    <li class="AspNet-Menu-Leaf">
                        <a href="/dg/ias/whatwedo/Pages/Agencies.aspx" class="AspNet-Menu-Link" title="Agencies">
                            Audit in Agencies</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="AspNet-Menu-Leaf">
                        <a href="/dg/ias/whatwedo/Pages/Commission.aspx" class="AspNet-Menu-Link" title="Audit in the Commission">
                            Audit in the Commission</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="AspNet-Menu-Leaf">
                        <a href="/dg/ias/whatwedo/reports/Pages/Home.aspx" class="AspNet-Menu-Link" title="IAS reports">
                            Our Reports</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="AspNet-Menu-Leaf">
                        <a href="/dg/ias/whatwedo/Pages/Listofportfolios.aspx" class="AspNet-Menu-Link" title="List of portfolios">
                            List of portfolios</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="AspNet-Menu-Leaf">
                        <a href="/dg/ias/whatwedo/Pages/ITAudit.aspx" class="AspNet-Menu-Link" title="IT Audit">
                            IT Audit</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="AspNet-Menu-Leaf">
                        <a href="/dg/ias/whatwedo/Pages/GRC.aspx" class="AspNet-Menu-Link" title="Description of the audit tool GRC">
                            Our Audit Tool: GRC</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="AspNet-Menu-Leaf">
                <a href="/dg/ias/knowledgesharing/Pages/Home.aspx" class="AspNet-Menu-Link">
                    Knowledge Sharing</a>
            </li>
            <li class="AspNet-Menu-Leaf">
                <a href="/dg/ias/tools/Pages/Home.aspx" class="AspNet-Menu-Link" title="Tools and procedures">
                    Tools &amp; Procedures</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

</div>
```

the JS I use:

```
$('.AspNet-Menu-WithChildren a').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault();
    $('.AspNet-Menu-WithChildren ul').slideToggle('slow', function() {
    });
});
```

the CSS that interferes (I think there's more but.. I guess that's enough)

```
ul.AspNet-Menu ul {
visibility: visible !important;
}

ul.AspNet-Menu ul {
display: block !important;
}
```

Comment: The question is: why do you use `!important` ? The use of that keyword should be very very limited and for such a thing I don't think it is necessary. You generally should review your CSS and rather use specificity. Anyway, without the rest of the CSS, it's difficult to tell you how to eventually change it.

Comment: He can't change the files, so I doubt that he made them.

Comment: God no, I didn't make that CSS. I arrived in the project long after the website was built, and there are like 20 websites based on that server-side code, so changing it would have to implicate tens of webmasters and fixes.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet you can include some of your own CSS. Find a way to do this and make the style:

```
html body .importantHide { display:none!important;}
```

Make the javascript like this:

```
$('.AspNet-Menu-WithChildren a').click(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.AspNet-Menu-WithChildren ul').slideToggle('slow', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('importantHide');
    });
});​
```

This will add a class to make it stay hidden. You might have to change a few things to make it look good. You can do that on your own. If not, just ask!

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Allan/h2PVT/2/

Comment: That seems like the solution! Didn't think to "tackle" it by adding an extra class via my JS:) The expand animation is not fading but I will try to work that out.. If you have any idea why give me a tip:) Otherwise, answer picked!

Comment: actually I think I know why: Is there a way to first toggle the class and then do the slidetoggle?

Comment: This would just make it not animate when to contracts. You have to make a little more code that will detect if this class is applied if it is you must remove it but before you make the animation. If it is not applied you must add it AFTER the animation. Does that make sense?

Comment: Or I could use something slideup.. ? $("#term").click(function
{
//find any description currently shown
//slide up and remove class
$(".shownDescription").slideUp(slow).removeClass('.shownDescription');
//slide down selected description
//add class for tracking
$(this).slideDown(slow).addClass('shownDescription');
})

Comment: I guess I will have to use another function because there I want when I slidedown one entry the other ones that are open to slideup... so i will have to detect which one is open and which not

Answer (score 0):

Browsers determine what CSS rulesets to apply to an element [based on a number of criteria](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/cascade), two of which are `!important` and selector specificity. I'm not entirely sure, but I'm thinking that you can beat `!important` by using a more specific selector (e.g. `ul.AspNet-Menu ul.someClass`).

Barring that, you might want to try overriding the CSS by placing an equally-important ruleset. This has to be a ruleset that is interpreted after your static server CSS.

```
ul.AspNet-Menu ul { 
    visibility : inherit !important;
    display : inherit !important;
}
```

Now this is all untested and I'm just theory-crafting here, so you might want to check it out for yourself. :)

Comment: If you try to crush the !importants with new ones, you just end up re-interfering with the slideToggle anyway.. It's a vicious circle..

Answer (score -1):

is there a reason you are using !important here. if you take it out and remove the visibilty rules from your selectors: it works fine

http://jsfiddle.net/ollie/8MRA5/

Comment: as I said in the description, I can't touch(delete or modify) this css as it's server-side :(